# Wireshark localhost traffic capture

Tags: networking, localhost, wireshark, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I wrote a simple server app in C which runs on localhost. How to capture localhost traffic using Wireshark?

Comment: Why this question got closed?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

If you're using Windows  <strike>it's not possible</strike> - read below. You can use the local address of your machine instead and then you'll be able to capture stuff. See **[CaptureSetup/Loopback](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback)**.

> Summary: you can capture on the
>   loopback interface on Linux, on
>   various BSDs including Mac OS X, and
>   on Digital/Tru64 UNIX, and you might
>   be able to do it on Irix and AIX, but
>   you definitely **cannot do so on
>   Solaris, HP-UX...**.

Although the page mentions that this is not possible on Windows using Wireshark alone, you can actually record it using a workaround as mentioned in a [different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43835383/1242922).

---

EDIT: Some 3 years later, this answer is no longer completely correct. The linked page contains **instructions for capturing on the loopback interface**.

Comment: feuGene's answer actually does work.

Comment: @GWLlosa Yup. *You can use the local address of your machine*.

Comment: I found it was not sufficient to simply put your own IP in wireshark instead of loopback;  adding the route was necessary for it to work in my situation.

Comment: Thanks. On OS X, the loopback interface is lo0. Choosing en1 or whatever your default is won't work, it seems.

Comment: For setting up the loopback adapter, I found this youtube video useful. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KsWICPPO_N8

Comment: Please try Npcap: https://github.com/nmap/npcap, it is based on WinPcap and supports loopback traffic capturing on Windows. Npcap is a subproject of Nmap (http://nmap.org/), so please report any issues on Nmap's development list (http://seclists.org/nmap-dev/).

Comment: `OSX 10.10.5`, `Wireshark 2.2.6`: I chose `Loopback lo0` for the Capture, but when I used TCP sockets to send data between a client and server, the Wireshark window remained completely blank.  I tried it several times--nothing.  Then I typed tcp into the "Apply a display filter" textbox, and voila! Data appeared.  On successive TCP transmissions, I didn't have to type anything for a filter.

Answer (score 56):

For some reason, none of previous answers worked in my case, so I'll post something that did the trick. There is a little jewel called [RawCap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap) that can capture localhost traffic on Windows. Advantages:

- only 17 kB!
- no external libraries needed
- extremely simple to use (just start it, choose the loopback interface and destination file and that's all)

After the traffic has been captured, you can open it and examine in Wireshark normally. The only disadvantage that I found is that you cannot set filters, i.e. you have to capture all localhost traffic which can be heavy. There is also one [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712242/using-rawcap-to-sniff-windows-localhost) regarding Windows XP SP 3.

Few more advices:

- [Wireshark wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback)

Comment: no setup required and was quite simple.

Comment: And you can have Wireshark read RawCap's output instantly, giving you live capturing. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 49):

On Windows platform, it is also possible to capture localhost traffic using Wireshark.
What you need to do is to install the [Microsoft loopback adapter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/842561/how-to-install-the-microsoft-loopback-adapter-in-microsoft-windows-ser), and then sniff on it.

Comment: ciphor, have you successfully done this?  this is in direct contradiction to cnicutar's answer.

Comment: yes, I've done it successfully.

Comment: And how? Didn't get it working.

Comment: I got this to work all the same on Win 7. Device Manager -> Add Legacy Hardware -> I'll pick -> Networking -> Microsoft -> Loopback adapter.  Once it's installed, configure it with an IP address of your chosing. Then: **reinstall wireshark** so that it will reinstall the capture driver on the new interface - this must be performed any time you add new interfaces to windows, loopback or real.

Comment: Followed @antiduh instructions on Win 7 and while I did see some netbios queries, I did not see HTTP traffic on localhost.

Comment: For setting up the loopback adapter on Windows 7, I found this youtube video useful. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KsWICPPO_N8

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on windows 8 - can see the loopback adapter in wireshark, and it's IP functions as a loopback, but no traffic is logged.

Comment: The [Wireshark Wiki](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback) mentions issues with this adapter, e.g. "but it will not work on the 127.0.0.1 IP addresses; it will take its own IP address".

Comment: Instead of reinstalling wireshark just restart the driver in command prompt **net stop npf && net start npf**

Answer (score 26):

I haven't actually tried this, but this answer from the web sounds promising:

> Wireshark can't actually capture local packets on windows XP due to
>   the nature of the windows TCP stack. When packets are sent and
>   received on the same machine they don't seem to cross the network
>   boundary that wireshark monitors.
>
> However there is a way around this, you can route the local traffic
>   out via your network gateway (router) by setting up a (temporary)
>   static route on your windows XP machine.
>
> Say your XP IP address is 192.168.0.2 and your gateway (router)
>   address is 192.168.0.1 you could run the following command from
>   windows XP command line to force all local traffic out and back across
>   the network boundary, so wireshark could then track the data (note
>   that wireshark will report packets twice in this scenario, once when
>   they leave your pc and once when they return).
>
> `route add 192.168.0.2 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.0.1 metric 1`

http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1037087, accessed just now.

Comment: I tried this, and found that it worked very well.

Comment: not work on win 7 32bit

Answer (score 12):

You can view loopback traffic live in Wireshark by having it read [RawCap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap)'s output instantly. [cmaynard](https://ask.wireshark.org/users/30/cmaynard/) describes this ingenious [approach at the Wireshark forums](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/29211/how-can-wireshark-capture-local-host-traffic-on-windows?page=1&focusedAnswerId=29269#29269). I will cite it here:

> [...] if you want to view live traffic in Wireshark, you can still do it by running RawCap from one command-line and running Wireshark from another. Assuming you have cygwin's tail available, this could be accomplished using something like so:
>
> `cmd1: RawCap.exe -f 127.0.0.1 dumpfile.pcap`
>
> `cmd2: tail -c +0 -f dumpfile.pcap | Wireshark.exe -k -i -`

It requires cygwin's tail, and I could not find a way to do this with Windows' out-of-the-box tools. His approach works very fine for me and allows me to use all of Wiresharks filter capabilities on captured loopback traffic live.

Comment: For me the essential part was to start the second cmd command with some delay, otherwise Wireshark could not read the .pcap file. Presumably, because there needs to be some recorded traffic in it to start with.

Comment: This should be accepted answer (it is enough to run cmd2 from git bash)

Comment: **An update**: Netresec just announced today (Jan 30, 2020) a new version of RawCap that now supports writing to a pipe or to `stdout`.  So as of today, the solution provided above can be simplified as follows, with no `tail` required:
  
    `RawCap.exe -q 127.0.0.1 - | Wireshark.exe -i - -k`
  
You can read more about the new RawCap features on the RawCap Redux announcement page here: https://www.netresec.com/?page=Blog&month=2020-01&post=RawCap-Redux

Answer (score 11):

Please try Npcap: https://github.com/nmap/npcap, it is based on WinPcap and supports loopback traffic capturing on Windows. Npcap is a subproject of Nmap (http://nmap.org/), so please report any issues on Nmap's development list (http://seclists.org/nmap-dev/).

Comment: Option #1 from the wireshark's documentation `Starting from Windows Vista: 
Npcap is an update of WinPcap using NDIS 6 Light-Weight Filter (LWF), done by Yang Luo for Nmap project during Google Summer of Code 2013 and 2015. Npcap has added many features compared to the legacy WinPcap.`

Comment: You can download the installer from here: https://nmap.org/npcap/

Comment: It is good to know that NPcap has some license limitations for use in business environments.

Answer (score 9):

For **Windows**,

You cannot capture packets for **Local Loopback** in **Wireshark** however, you can use a very tiny but useful program called **RawCap**;

[RawCap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap)

Run **RawCap** on **command prompt** and select the **Loopback Pseudo-Interface** (127.0.0.1) then just write the name of the packet capture file (**.pcap**)

A simple demo is as below;

```
C:\Users\Levent\Desktop\rawcap>rawcap
Interfaces:
 0.     169.254.125.51  Local Area Connection* 12       Wireless80211
 1.     192.168.2.254   Wi-Fi   Wireless80211
 2.     169.254.214.165 Ethernet        Ethernet
 3.     192.168.56.1    VirtualBox Host-Only Network    Ethernet
 4.     127.0.0.1       Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1     Loopback
Select interface to sniff [default '0']: 4
Output path or filename [default 'dumpfile.pcap']: test.pcap
Sniffing IP : 127.0.0.1
File        : test.pcap
Packets     : 48^C
```

Answer (score 6):

You cannot capture loopback on Solaris, HP-UX, or Windows, however you can very easily work around this limitation by using a tool like **[RawCap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap)**.

RawCap can capture raw packets on any ip including `127.0.0.1` (localhost/loopback). Rawcap can also generate a `pcap` file. You can open and analyze the `pcap` file with **Wireshark**.

See [here](http://carminedimascio.com/2014/03/rawcap-and-wireshark-how-to-capture-and-analyze-local-traffic-from-host-machine-to-itself/) for full details on how to monitor localhost using RawCap and Wireshark.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can monitor the localhost traffic using the Npcap Loopback Adapter