# C#-Server / C++ Client: Socket.Accept() never finishes

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, tcp

I'm writing a simple C++ client that should connect to a C# server. And, while the client runs throught fine and even states it sent a bunch of bites, the C# server never gets past `listener.Acceppt()`:

```
Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
// Program is suspended while waiting for an incoming connection.
Socket handler = listener.Accept();
```

I took the server source from here: [Microsoft MSDN: Synchronous Server Socket Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/6y0e13d3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The client code I use can be found here: [Microsoft MSDN: Complete Winsock Client Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I also checked to server with the according [C# client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/kb5kfec7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which worked fine. I also checked the return values of the client, which also looked pretty plausible. So I'd guess the problem lies somewhere in how C++ / C# handle the details.

I tried Wireshark to find some hints, but mysteriously there was absolutely no trace of any communication on the used port (11000).

Where should I start looking to solve this issue?

**Update:** All communication at the moment runs just locally. I tried my IPAddress (from `ipconfig`) and `127.0.0.1` for both server and client.

I just have one network adapter installed, I use that IP adress. The client checks the `getaddrinfo(argv[1], DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result)` and returns valid information (e.g. TCP as protocol). `connect()` returns `0`, which should be ok.

**Update 2:**
I tried different combinations of C++/C# Server-Client-Setups:

- C++-Server, C++ Client: Works
- C++-Server, C# Client: Works
- C#-Server, C# Client: Works
- C#-Server, C++ Client: Does not work
- C#-Server, [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/): Works

**Update 3:** I tried Wireshark on the other Server-Client constellations, but neither of them did show any traffic on `tcp.port == 11000`, although they did work (see Update 2). It looks like Wireshark does not show any results, because everything is just local (see [Wireshark localhost traffic capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847168/wireshark-localhost-traffic-capture))

Comment: Wh... what?  Just to be sure - you are saying that the client connected OK and sent data, but the server accept() never returned?

Comment: ' tried Wireshark to find some hints, but mysteriously there was absolutely no trace of any communication on the used port (11000)' - check your IP addresses...  you are not communicating with the server you think you are.

Comment: I just have one network adapter installed, I use that IP adress. The client checks the `getaddrinfo(argv[1], DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result)` and returns valid information (e.g. TCP as protocol). `connect()` returns `0`, which should be ok.

Comment: I cannot think of any way that a connect could succeed at the client and accept() not return at the server IF the client is indeed connecting to the server you think it is.

Comment: I tried changing small things, like changing the port on the server, but not the client:  the connect fails. Changing the client port to the same value as the server: connect succeeds...

Comment: If your client can actually connect to the proper IP address and port, it means that something else must be listening. Maybe you didn't shutdown a different instance of the server properly? Also, note that the C# server is specifying IPv4, while the client doesn't - and the C# server only ever listens on the first IP address it finds. It might be a better idea to bind to `IPAddress.Any`.

Comment: Thanks! Binding to `IPAddress.Any` and changing to `hints.ai_family = AF_INET` did not help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.
The connection with winsock is asynchronous. And the example in C# that you are using is synchronous.
You have to use a Asynchronous example to get communication with your C++ code.

I used this two examples!

C Sharp server
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx

C plus plus client
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737591(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Just provide some basic steps to make sure you are giving a good answer.

Comment: @Monica Cid Can you please tell me in details. I am trying to do the same. I copied the whole code from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737591(v=vs.85).aspx llink. But, I think I am not getting the desired result. What changes should I make? Please suggest me.