# wireshark capture filter on loopback interface

Tags: wireshark, npcap

selecting the loopback interface **"Npcap Loopback Adapter"** to capture locahost traffic and set the "capture filter" (no the display filter) on "tcp" when i start the capture i don't see anything, removing the filter i see packets of different protocols (tcp packets included)

i need to capture localhost packets to inspect SOAP messages sent and received on my machine (i've the soap service and the client running on my machine).

Comment: I think this has already been answered in these threads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847168/wireshark-localhost-traffic-capture ---
https://superuser.com/questions/906402/wireshark-loopback-on-mac-os-x ---
https://superuser.com/questions/508623/how-can-i-see-127-0-0-1-traffic-on-windows-using-wireshark