# Packets sent from QUdpSocket are not seen in Wireshark

Tags: c++, qt, wireshark, qudpsocket

I'm trying to see my outgoing UDP traffic in Wireshark.

I created new socket and bind it to my QHostAddress::LocalHost with no errors. I then sent some data writeDatagram and the return value is correct, but I see no outgoing traffic in Wireshark.

```
// create a socket called from init() 
socket = new QUdpSocket(this);
bool ret = socket->bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 47000);
if (ret == false)
   {
    printf("failed to bind socket\n");
   }    


// create and sent some data called from send()
QHostAddress addr("192.168.5.12"); // addr of my other computer
qint64 size = socket->writeDatagram(QByteArray("udp data"),addr,47000);

printf("sent %d\n",size); // correct size sent 8
```

I checked the firewall setting and it's the same result if I turn it off.

Comment: What platform are you on? [WinPcap can not capture from loopback device out of the box on windows](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback). Can you see any other loopback traffic? Maybe try `ping localhost` and see if that generates any traffic in wireshark...

Comment: What operating system are you on? QHostAddress::LocalHost should resolve to the loopback address which wireshark cannot listen to on windows (and some others) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847168/wireshark-localhost-traffic-capture

Comment: What network device are you listening to on wireshark?

Comment: @Mike, Sorry for not stating platform It was 12AM and I was working late. I'm on Windows 7. I don't see any traffic when pinging localhost. I changed QHostAddress::LocalHost to my network address and now I see packets. Thank you all for the help. I can't believe I didn't try this. SOLVED.

Comment: No worries :)
You can see what Qt sends on wireshark only if you are able to see ICMP packets from `ping localhost`. You might want to refer to the link in my previous comment if you want to try to get wireshark to capture loopback traffic (haven't tried the instructions myself though).

Comment: A simpler solution might be to run the application on two separate devices (one of them could be a VM), if you are looking for a fast way to inspect some packets. This way, the traffic is no longer loopback traffic.

Comment: Which version of Wireshark are you using? 3.0.0 and later ship with Npcap, which supports loopback capture.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED by changing the QHostAddress from localhost to assigned router address.